# TFile.ReadAllText with TEncoding.UTF8 omits first 3 chars

Tags: delphi, utf-8, text-files, delphi-xe2

I have a UTF-8 text file which starts with this line:

```
<HEAD><META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 10.00.9200.16521"><body>
```

When I read this file with `TFile.ReadAllText` with TEncoding.UTF8:

```
MyStr := TFile.ReadAllText(ThisFileNamePath, TEncoding.UTF8);
```

then the first 3 characters of the text file are omitted, so MyStr results in:

```
'AD><META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 10.00.9200.16521"><body>...'
```

However, when I read this file with `TFile.ReadAllText` without TEncoding.UTF8:

```
MyStr := TFile.ReadAllText(ThisFileNamePath);
```

then the file is read completely and correctly:

```
<HEAD><META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 10.00.9200.16521"><body>...
```

Does `TFile.ReadAllText` have a bug?

Comment: As an aside, and for reference, it is preferred to not include things like "Delphi" and "Delphi XE2" in the question title - the tags take care of this information ;)

Comment: I just wanted to be as explicit as possible.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  It is just a matter of convention and tidiness -- see : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/222049

Comment: I know this is old, but i hope [this bug entry to embarcaderos qc portal will result in an API fix by them](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14120)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first three bytes are skipped because the RTL code assumes that the file contains a UTF-8 BOM. Clearly your file does not.

The `TUTF8Encoding` class implements a `GetPreamble` method that specifies the `UTF-8` BOM. And `ReadAllBytes` skips the preamble specified by the encoding that you pass.

One simple solution would be to read the file into a byte array and then use `TEncoding.UTF8.GetString` to decode it into a string.

```
var
  Bytes: TBytes;
  Str: string;
....
Bytes := TFile.ReadAllBytes(FileName);
Str := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Bytes);
```

An more comprehensive alternative would be to make a `TEncoding` instance that ignored the UTF-8 BOM.

```
type
  TUTF8EncodingWithoutBOM = class(TUTF8Encoding)
  public
    function Clone: TEncoding; override;
    function GetPreamble: TBytes; override;
  end;

function TUTF8EncodingWithoutBOM.Clone: TEncoding;
begin
  Result := TUTF8EncodingWithoutBOM.Create;
end;

function TUTF8EncodingWithoutBOM.GetPreamble: TBytes;
begin
  Result := nil;
end;
```

Instantiate one of these (you only need one instance per process) and pass it to `TFile.ReadAllText`.

The advantage of using a singleton instance of `TUTF8EncodingWithoutBOM` is that you can use it anywhere that expects a `TEncoding`.

Comment: If it doesn't have a BOM and UTF-8 otherwise gets it right, would in not be safe to conclude that it's just a normal ASCII file?  Why not just use OP's approach but change the encoding to `TEncoding.ASCII`?

Comment: @J... Why would the lack of a BOM signify anything? BOMs are a non-standard Windows thing. In the rest of the computing world, files don't have BOMs. Also, the asker clearly states that it is a UTF-8 file. If you think otherwise then your comment is addressed to the wrong person.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that BOMs were a Windows thing - the question was primarily whether or not its absence was sufficient to conclude a different format.  It seems not.  Good information.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan David, thank you for your as always brilliant answer!
However, what happens if the UTF-8 file DOES have a BOM? (Which I cannot predict). Will in this case the BOM erroneously be read into the string variable?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You need to read the first 3 bytes and detect the BOM if you are wanting to cope with all variations.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Which most fast and best procedure would you suggest to read and test the first 3 bytes? (AFAIK there are several BOM types - should I test for all of them?) - Then I will pack all this into a function `MyTFileReadAllText` which gives me a correct result in all cases.

Comment: Well, most fast is asking a lot! You can use ReadAllBytes and then compare the beginning of the byte array against SomeEncoding.GetPreamble.

Comment: That BOM lookup had to be implemented into TFile. Did someone create a QC?

Comment: BOM is not a non-standard Windows thing, it is a thing covered by the Unicode standard; if it is there, you should respect it. http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom1

Comment: @Jeroen Yes, I expressed that badly. BOMs are optional, for many situations they must be omitted, they tend to be found on Windows but not so much on *nix.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that highly depends at which *nix based software systems you look. Basically any serious system I've seen (*nix or not) handles Unicode BOMs. But there is a lot of crap out there that doesn't (:

Comment: @Jeroen That's not the issue. The issue is whether or not the tools create new files with BOMs. I agree that all half decent tools handle BOMs. Most *nix editors won't include a BOM when creating a file.

Comment: For what it is worth, Emacs, VIM, Eclipse, Xcode and TextWrangler support BOM. There are many more, but these are very popular coding environments on various *nix based systems.

Comment: @Jeroen Yes, but I'm not talking about "supporting" BOMs am I?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I voted for your `ReadAllBytes` solution which seems the most compatible and most easy solution to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the value you pass to ReadAllText is not the Default Encoding (when you check how it's implemented), it's an enforced encoding if you pass something other than Nil. Internally it calls other method of TEncoding that does have an extra default encoding parameter (for when the foundEncoding var parameter is set to nil and no encoding could be detected)

I was trying to make methods to work with Stream, based on the TFile.ReadAllText code and ended up with this, note the "DefaultEncoding=nil" (=nil so that no extra overloaded method needed) I use and the "ForceDefaultEncoding=false" (to say we always want to use that encoding)

```
function ReadAllBytes(const Stream: TStream): TBytes;
begin
  var LFileSize := Stream.Size;
  {$IFDEF CPU32BITS}
  if LFileSize > MaxInt then
    raise EInOutError.CreateRes(@SFileTooLong);
  {$ENDIF}
  SetLength(Result, LFileSize);
  Stream.ReadBuffer(result, Length(result));
end;

function ReadAllText(const Stream: TStream; const DefaultEncoding: TEncoding = nil; const ForceDefaultEncoding: Boolean = false): string;
var FoundEncoding: TEncoding;
begin
  if ForceDefaultEncoding then
    FoundEncoding := DefaultEncoding;
  var Buff := ReadAllBytes(Stream);
  var BOMLength := TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding(Buff, FoundEncoding, DefaultEncoding);
  result := FoundEncoding.GetString(Buff, BOMLength, Length(Buff) - BOMLength);
end;
```

Comment: that code is currently at https://github.com/Zoomicon/READCOM_App/tree/master/Zoomicon.Text (untested yet and may move to own repo), based on TFile.ReadAllText